# Setting the colour of one class to display with "No Colour" Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to display one class within a binary image as "transparent" or "no colour".

I have tried the following:

```
var NDVIclass2Clipped = NDVIclass2.clip(geometry)
Map.addLayer(NDVIclass2Clipped,{palette:['**transparent**','yellow']},'BareGround 2019');
```

It does not work though.

Should that be the CSS for no colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify transparency at the palette level.  Instead, you should mask the parts of the image you want to be transparent.

This will preserve the parts of the image where the value is 1 and mask everything else:

```
var masked = NDVIclass2.clip(geometry).updateMask(NDVIclass2.eq(1))
```

Comment: This works a treat. Many thanks fro your speedy reply!